# Qt program built in Windows 10 run slower than one built in Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, windows-10

I have a Qt program built using Qt5.9.8 on *Windows 7*. The startup load time for the program after build is normally 6s. When I transferred the source code to *Windows 10* and build it in Qt Creator, the startup load time for the program increased to over 2 minutes, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you build it in the debug mode?

Comment: I tried it in both debug and release mode, the load time increased to over 2 minutes for both debug and release mode